# WPF converter value type is always "RuntimeType"

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, converters

I am trying to change `Button`'s visibility based on the value selected in `ComboBox`.

`ComboBox` data source is `List<Type>`

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Objects}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedObject}"
```

Button bound like this:

```
<Button Visibility="{Binding SelectedObject, Converter={StaticResource TypeToVisibilityConverter}, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

TypeToVisibilityConverter:

```
public class TypeToVisibilityConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value == null) return null;

        if (value is CmQuote)
            return Visibility.Visible;
        else
            return Visibility.Hidden;
    }
}
```

For some reason, when the type `CmQuote` is selected in `ComboBox`, the `value` name is correct, which is `CmQuote`, but the actual type is `RuntimeType` and not CmQuote, thus always making if statement false.

I have also tried doing `typeof(value)` and `value.GetType() == typeof(CmQuote)`

How can I pass in a type to this converter, and check if it's a specific type at runtime?

**EDIT**: adding objects like this:

```
    private void InitializeObjects()
    {
        foreach (var assemblyName in Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetReferencedAssemblies())
        {
            if (assemblyName.Name == "cmFIX")
            {
                Assembly assembly = Assembly.Load(assemblyName);

                foreach (var type in assembly.GetTypes())
                {
                    if (type.Name.Substring(0, 2) == "Cm")
                    {
                        Objects.Add(type);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        Objects.Add(typeof(string));
    }
```

Comment: also: don't return null, where Visibility is expected. return some Visibility. `if (value == null) return Visibility.Collapsed;`

Comment: @ASh Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: it would be better if you provided a [mcve], namely the part, where you create `Objects`

Comment: @ASh Updated question.

Comment: sorry, I somehow missed "ComboBox data source is `List<Type>`", it makes sense now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`value` received in converter is Type, not instance of any type. So `GetType()` returns `RuntimeType`.

make a cast and compare Type with another Type, obtained by `typeof()` operator:

```
public class TypeToVisibilityConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        Type t = value as Type;

        if (t == typeof(CmQuote))
            return Visibility.Visible;

        return Visibility.Hidden;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I will test this tomorow and mark your answer.